# What the reason for Kotlin to create jar file execute a class?

Tags: java, kotlin, javac

Despite the fact that both java and Kotlin share the same JVM and same compiler. I can see the only Kotlin always need a jar to execute the file but not java

Kotlin

```
kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
kotlinc hello.kt -d hello.jar
```

Java

```
javac hello.java 
java hello
```

Can some one explain me why?

Comment: Notice that `-include-runtime`.

Answer (score 2):

Executable Kotlin code need its runtime (packaged as a JAR) to do so, since it doesn't compile down directly to native Java (i.e. exclusive of all non-standard JRE libraries) code as `javac` (with no arguments) would do

If you did have a native `.class` file from Kotlin, you'd probably still need to run `java -cp kotlin-<something>.jar hello`, where `<something>` could be [`stdlib` or `runtime`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-runtime)